# How can I get readable errors from React using webpack?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, debugging, npm, webpack

I tried the obvious, which was setting mode to production in my npm script as follows:

I changed it from:

```
"client": "webpack -w --config ./gen/config/webpack.config.js",
```

which defaults to production to

```
"client-dev": "webpack -w --mode development --config ./gen/config/webpack.config.js",
```

However this appeared to do nothing useful.

I need to do this via the npm command line so I can switch back and forth easily.

I need to be able to see the failing line in my React code so I can actually debug it.

Answer (score 0):

https://webpack.js.org/configuration/devtool/

Setting the appropriate setting for source maps will likely do what you want so that you can see the appropriate source file line reference in your developer tools.